# AllItems View of Query String: can I group using value in query string?

Tags: document-library, javascript, modal-dialog, query, query-string

Can I somehow how a query string to show a group of documents within a given library. Not one single item, but the AllItems like view. So within the library I have a grouping type of id value in a column that represents the collection the document belongs to. I would like to call a modal dialog that shows the relative documents based on selections made on the page....I am pretty sure I know how to do everything else, but I am wondering if this is possible with passing something like 'CollectionID' in a query string within the AllItems.aspx url Like.

.../Forms/AllItems.aspx?CollectionID=134

so this may seem silly, but I don't know which is why I am asking. appreciate anyone who can helps me out with this.

FYI. I have designer and js/jquery....that is the extent of the dev tools I am working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSLTListViewWebPart can read querystring parameters, you could try this:

```
.../Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterName=Title&FilterMultiValue=*something*
```

FilterName is a column. Hope this helps

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks man! appreciated!