# XSLTListViewWP: filter results based on javascript variable/other control on page?

Tags: list, javascript, jquery, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have some custom html/jquery form stuff on a page, and I would like to update a LVWP on another part of the page if a user adds something. So for example, the list view web part just shows items on a list, but I need them to go through my form to add a new item since there are numerous relational lists that get updated. Not a big deal that all works. But I do want to use a LVWP to show all requests currently being worked per the userID of the person submitting. So this is quite the overall parent list, and there may be multiple items that need shown.

Bottomline is I have all this worked out except, how can I pass a parameter/variable to a LVWP that is one a page using javascript/jquery? Each time the user adds an item, I would like to refresh the view and pass new ID for the LVWP to use as a filter like a query string or something?

Does this make sense? All help is always appreciated!

Comment: Could it be you are looking for something like this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45944/allitems-view-of-query-string-can-i-group-using-value-in-query-string ?

Comment: lol. perhaps but i get how you call that in a dialog, how can i use that if its a static webpart on the page? the idea is exactly what I need, I just don't know how to use it in that way. thanks

Comment: Any XSLTListViewWebPart will pick up the querystring and filter based on it. I use this to enable simple "search" functionality over a set of XSLTListViewWebParts with different views. A simple input and some JS setting window.location.href