# Advanced filtering XsltListViewWebPart with custom webpart

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part

I have got simple list rendered by XsltListViewWebPart. I would like to create additional filtering options using custom visual web part to provide list item id's to filter XsltListViewWebPart on same page. How to pass filtered id's from custom visual web part to XsltListViewWebPart?

Comment: Would this help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/45963/627 ?

Comment: I am not allowed to use query string (because potential number of filtered items)

Comment: Maybe you could use any of the Filter Web Parts perhaps?